# IE / Edge browser checkbox slide not working Properly what can I do

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I have a switch button. Which is working fine with all the browsers except IE.
I was trying to solve it and I could not find any solution.

Here is my code snippet:

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {display:none;}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<h2>Toggle Switch</h2>
<label class="switch">
<input type="hidden">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

All major browser working fine but IE/ Edge browser not working Properly.

How can I solve this?

Thanks

Comment: What does "not working properly" mean? Please read through this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Comment: Which IE version are you trying to make it work on?

Comment: I use IE 10 Version